# Unknown Property Ticks Error on Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I ran into an error when I tried to change the label of my x axis to be that of `ages_x`. Currently, it's `x_indexes`, which is the length of the `ages_x`. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

ages_x = [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]
x_indexes=np.arange(len(ages_x))
width= 0.25

dev_y = [38496, 42000, 46752, 49320, 53200, 56000, 62316, 64928, 67317, 68748, 73752]
plt.bar(x_indexes, dev_y, width=width, color= '#444444', label= 'All Devs')

py_dev_y = [45372, 48876, 53850, 57287, 63016, 65998, 70003, 70000, 71496, 75370, 83640]
plt.bar(x_indexes - width, py_dev_y, width=width,  label= 'Python')

js_dev_y = [37810, 43515, 46823, 49293, 53437, 56373, 62375, 66674, 68745, 68746, 74583]
plt.bar(x_indexes + width, js_dev_y, width=width,  label= 'JavaScript')



plt.title('Median Salary (USD) by Age')
plt.xlabel('Ages')
plt.ylabel('Median Salary (USD)')
plt.legend()
plt.xticks(ticks=x_indexes, labels= ages_x)
plt.tight_layout()


plt.show()
```

Here's the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-ad69a2071340> in <module>()
     24 plt.ylabel('Median Salary (USD)')
     25 plt.legend()
---> 26 plt.xticks(ticks=x_indexes, labels= ages_x)
     27 plt.tight_layout()
     28 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in xticks(*args, **kwargs)
   1705     if len(kwargs):
   1706         for l in labels:
-> 1707             l.update(kwargs)
   1708 
   1709     return locs, silent_list('Text xticklabel', labels)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py in update(self, kwargs)
    241         """
    242         bbox = kwargs.pop('bbox', None)
--> 243         super(Text, self).update(kwargs)
    244         if bbox:
    245             self.set_bbox(bbox)  # depends on font properties

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in update(self, props)
    883         try:
    884             ret = [_update_property(self, k, v)
--> 885                    for k, v in props.items()]
    886         finally:
    887             self.eventson = store

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    883         try:
    884             ret = [_update_property(self, k, v)
--> 885                    for k, v in props.items()]
    886         finally:
    887             self.eventson = store

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in _update_property(self, k, v)
    876                 func = getattr(self, 'set_' + k, None)
    877                 if func is None or not six.callable(func):
--> 878                     raise AttributeError('Unknown property %s' % k)
    879                 return func(v)
    880 

AttributeError: Unknown property ticks
```

Comment: With the code as written, it runs without errors in matplotlib 3.3.2. This style seems to have been added in v3.1.0. I'm voting to close as not reproducible.

Comment: Works for me as well with  `matplotlib.__version__ =='3.1.3'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using an old verison of Matplotlib

Update to a newer version and your code should run fine. I just ran your code on matplotlib 3.3.2 and it works fine.